# C++ Boost 1.66 using Beast http request Parser for parsing an string

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, httprequest, boost-beast

I'm not using beast http server in my project but I was searching for a solution to parse an http request in form of std::string in my program ,is it possible to use boost/beast/http/parser.hpp in this case and if so it would be Great if you give an example in code.
Thanks aloot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible:

```
std::string s =
    "POST /cgi/message.php HTTP/1.1\r\n"
    "Content-Length: 5\r\n"
    "\r\n"
    "abcde";
error_code ec;
request_parser<string_body> p;
p.put(boost::asio::buffer(s), ec);
```

Comment: ```bad method``` is written to the ```error_code``` in your example.
(boost 1.68)

Comment: Whoops, sorry about that! The string contained an HTTP response instead of a request. I have updated the code sample.