# How to use boost::http::response_parser for parsing string?

Tags: http, httpresponse, boost-beast

I wanted to parse my own data using response_parser of boost::http. All the documentation I found is linked with http::request of boost. I have written my own SSLLink to get data. I want to feed the data incrementally to response_parser and check if a complete message has been parsed.

I found this answer somewhat relevant:  [Parse Response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49756730/c-boost-1-66-using-beast-http-request-parser-for-parsing-an-string). but it doesn't not provide method to feed data incrementally.

Answer (score 1):

This is fully explained in the documentation: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/using_http/buffer_oriented_parsing.html