# Asynchronous read header with Boost.Beast

Tags: c++, http, asynchronous, boost, boost-beast

I try to read the header separately, but I get an error when work with any host.

Class members:

```
boost::asio::io_context ioc_;
// The SSL context is required, and holds certificates
boost::asio::ssl::context ctx_{boost::asio::ssl::context::sslv23_client};
boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> stream_{ioc_, ctx_}; // https
boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket_{ioc_}; // http
boost::beast::http::request_parser<boost::beast::http::string_body> header_parser_;
boost::asio::streambuf strbuf_;
```

Methods:

```
void AsyncHttpClient::onWrite(boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred)
{
  boost::ignore_unused(bytes_transferred);

  if(ec)
    return fail(ec, "write");

  if (https_mode_) {
    boost::beast::http::async_read_header(socket_, strbuf_, header_parser_, std::bind(&AsyncHttpClient::onReadHeader, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2));
  }
  else {
    // Receive the HTTP response
    boost::beast::http::async_read_header(socket_, strbuf_, header_parser_, std::bind(&AsyncHttpClient::onReadHeader, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2));
  }
}

void AsyncHttpClient::onReadHeader(boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred)
{
  boost::ignore_unused(bytes_transferred);

  std::cout << bytes_transferred << std::endl;

  if(ec)
    return fail(ec, "read header"); // Here is the error `bad method`

  std::string header_{boost::asio::buffers_begin(strbuf_.data()), boost::asio::buffers_begin(strbuf_.data()) + static_cast<signed long>(bytes_transferred)};
  std::cout << header_ << std::endl;

  std::string s =
      "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
      "Content-Length: 5\r\n"
      "\r\n"
      "*****";
  boost::beast::error_code ec_;
  boost::beast::http::request_parser<boost::beast::http::string_body> p;
  p.put(boost::asio::buffer(s), ec_);
  if (ec_) {
    return fail(ec_, "parse header"); // Here is the error `bad method`
  }
}
```

`fail`'s code:

```
void AsyncHttpClient::fail(boost::system::error_code ec, const char *what)
{
  std::cerr << what << ": " << ec.message() << "\n";
}
```

Header of response:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Server: SimpleHTTP/0.6 Python/3.6.6
Date: Wed, 03 Oct 2018 13:02:12 GMT
Content-type: text/x-c++src
Content-Length: 205
Last-Modified: Mon, 17 Sep 2018 14:04:14 GMT
```

Moreover, the [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49757082/5494506) proposed by the developer of Boost.Beast does not work -- the same error.

Boost version 1.68

Am I doing something wrong?

**Edit**:

In the example was a typo. It should be:

```
std::string s =
    "POST /cgi/message.php HTTP/1.1\r\n"
    "Content-Length: 5\r\n"
    "\r\n"
    "abcde";
```

But the main problem with asynchronous reading header is not solved.

Comment: You haven't specified the type of the error

Comment: @user3159253, What is the type of error?

Comment: > " I get an error when work with any host"

What was the error? Type, message etc?

Comment: @user3159253, ```if(ec)``` -- it's true. ```ec.message()``` return ```bad method```. That's all I know about the error. I found [topic](https://github.com/boostorg/beast/issues/257), I think this is related to my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this problem.

It was necessary to use another parser

```
boost::beast::http::response_parser<boost::beast::http::file_body> header_parser_;
```

instead

```
boost::beast::http::request_parser<boost::beast::http::string_body> header_parser_;
```

Previously I tried everything, for some reason then it did not bring success.